# jquery toggle class taking more than 2 clicks instead of just 1 click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to toggle class on button click.  However, when I click on button it's not working.  But if I click 3 times, it toggles class.  My question is, why it's taking 3 clicks to toggle class?

Here is the js fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/WhiteSharks20692/enku5qun/5/

```
<script>
function toggle_class(classname)
{
    $('.' + classname).click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");

    });
}
</script>
```

Any idea what's wrong with the code?  Thanks.

Comment: Every time you click one of those elements you add an additional click handler to toggle the class...

Comment: @canonThanks for your reply.  Can you post some code to rectify my error?

Comment: no. Frankly, you should take what I just told you and examine your own code.